# drm:vmw_hostlog Failed to send host log message

Tags: virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu 16.04? (this might be wrong) Virtual Machine in VirtualBox 6.1 on a Windows 10 host that I use for my programming that has been working flawlessly for months, but for some reason as I came back to programming this week it initially gave me errors about file size. I went in and increased the size of the Virtual Disk to compensate, and now my VM boots to the error message in the title.

After searching that up, I found that it was most likely a display issue, so I did the whole dance of changing the Display adapter to VboxVGA, disabling 3D acceleration, and any combination of those two.

Although the error went away with a different graphics controller, it still just booted to an all black screen with no message.

I have logs, but I'm not sure which ones I need to post and I can't see anything particularly wrong in there as it seems like it just hangs.

What happened to my VM?

Answer (score 1):

Host: Linux Mint 19.1
Guest: KDE Neon 5.19

Solution: booting another (a previous) kernel. Whereas it still outputs the "failed to send log" error but does not break booting.

The [VboxVGA solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502540/why-does-drmvmw-host-log-vmwgfx-error-failed-to-send-host-log-message-sh) didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this issue by uninstalling virtualbox and installing it again but with the most recent version: 6.1.22

Hope this helps